# Is it possible to run Virtual Machines using another Virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, vps, xen

This might sound like a stupid question but i haven't had the correct answer yet.

If i have a high configuration vps from say Rackspace or any big company, then can i use Xen or any other virtualization on it for creating smaller vpses of reduced configuration ?

Answer (score 3):

You can. Without hardware virtualization support Xen provides only paravirtualisation which requires modified system software in the guests. Most Linux distributions come with Xen-compatible kernels. I think windows doesn't work on it.

But in general: Because you can it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: One of the experts i have contacted previously told me that the kernel will face conflicts in case there are any upgrades or modifications. Is it true ?

Comment: That's a possibility. That's why I said it's a bad idea :) There are tons of issues that might arise.

Comment: With XEN there should be no problem as long as the DomU-xen-part is not much newer than the Dom0-xen-part.

Answer (score 0):

I started my first experiments with XEN on a VirtualBox instance which was running on an XP-Laptop.

So the answer is - yes, you can. But only certain combinations will work. Only the first level of VM can take advantage of hardware-virtualization - the second must use software based features.